# Use find method when there are merged cells, vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, merge, find

I have a question about using the `.find` method in Excel VBA when there is a merged cell in the searching range. Here is the code:

```
Dim SearchCell As Range
Set SearchCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:="Open RMA*", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

SearchCell is empty after running the code, I guess because A26:K26 is merged as one cell while the value is "Open RMA"; I don't want to unmerge it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is problematic unless you extend the range to include the merged cell's range, changing A:A to A:D, for example.

An alternative approach would be:

```
Dim SearchCell As Range

If Not Application.IsNA(Application.Match("Open RMA*", Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
    Set SearchCell = Cells(Application.Match("Open RMA*", Range("A:A"), 0), 1)
    MsgBox "Found at " & SearchCell.Address
End If
```

It requires some better error checking, though, in case the value is not found. **Added** like this:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("Open RMA*", Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
    Set SearchCell = Cells(Application.Match("Open RMA*", Range("A:A"), 0), 1)
    MsgBox "Found at " & SearchCell.Address
End If
```

Comment: I came from the future to tell that even extending the range won't guarantee reliable results. I prefer `WorksheetFunction.Match` since it automatically stops if it can't find what I am looking for, so unwanted edits are avoided.