# Find method fails for first cell if range contains merged cells

Tags: excel, vba, find

My data looks like this:

```
A1: "a"  
A5: "b"  
A9: "c"  
A13: "d"
```

and VBA code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("A1:A16").Find("a", LookIn:=xlValues)
End Sub
```

Now if I leave it like this, .Find method works fine, and r becomes range with cell A1.
But if I merge cells A1-A4, A5-A8, A9-A12, A13-A16, .Find method fails on value "a". It will work for other values - "b", "c", and "d". It will just fail for value of first cell in range.

Any idea why this inconsistent behavior occurs?

PS. I just checked UI's "find and replace". It does fail the same way.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times before. Type this in google `excel vba find value in merged cells site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604353/use-find-method-when-there-are-merged-cells-vba-excel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241516/find-value-in-merged-cell

Comment: Keep in mind that merged cells are VBA's worst nightmare! =)

Comment: Siddharth Rout those questions you linked are just similar, but not the same. First one might be on the same topic, but it doesn't explain where data that's being searched is located. Find method has no problem finding values in subsequent merged cells. Just the first one.
Besides, those questions were asked over 5 and almost 8 years ago. MS Office version that was used by that time is already EOL.